# issue with JBOSS initializeContext()

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I have Websphere AS running project which i am migrating to JBoss ESP 6.2. But at time of deployment in JBoss its giving issue related to initializing context for datasource.

I am using following code for data source lookup from context

```
Context ctx = null;
DataSource dataSource = null;
Properties p = new Properties();
    try {

        ctx = new InitialContext();
        return dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/" + dataSourceStr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

**Exception in Console :**

```
 23:15:56,959 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.ibm.ejs.ns.jndi.CNInitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.SmartEAR.ear.Smarti.war:main" from Service Module Loader: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.ibm.ejs.ns.jndi.CNInitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.SmartEAR.ear.Smarti.war:main" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.processJndiEntries(WebConfiguration.java:683) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.<init>(WebConfiguration.java:134) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(WebConfiguration.java:194) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:158) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-2.jar:2.1.19-redhat-2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Any one have idea about what i am missing in JBOSS ?

Comment: have you configured datasource in JBoss? Please see [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration?_sscc=t).

Comment: Yes I configured with Name java:jboss/datasources/securityDS

Answer (score 0):

> Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.ibm.ejs.ns.jndi.CNInitialContextFactory

It seems to be that com.ibm.ejs.ns.jndi.CNInitialContextFactory is the factory class used by Websphere.

Probably, the JNDI binding configuration used by this line

> ctx = new InitialContext();

is still the suitable for Websphere but not for JBoss.

You should provide to JBoss the correct configuration, which is:

> java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
>   java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces